# Word for "centered" page as opposed to "recto/verso" pairs

Tags: typography

In bookmaking, in a left-to-right-reading language such as English, the terms *rēctō* (*folium rēctum*) and *versō* (*folium versum*) are used to differentiate the right-hand and left-hand pages of an open book.

Text on the *rēctō* page is typically shifted slightly to the left (toward the spine) and text on the *versō* page is typically shifted slightly to the right (again, toward the spine). Also, page numbers are often placed in one corner or the other, rather than centered.

[image]

But what about when a book is typeset with all pages centered, with the intention of it being published for single-page-at-a-time reading? Is there a word for that?

I was thinking perhaps *centrō* (*folium centrum*), but unfortunately I am very much not well-versed in Latin.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps "solo" ?

Comment: @BenVoigt — Interesting! And apparently it's a Latin word: https://www.online-latin-dictionary.com/latin-dictionary-flexion.php?lemma=SOLO100

Comment: Wrong word, you're looking for [this one](https://www.online-latin-dictionary.com/latin-dictionary-flexion.php?lemma=SOLUS100), an adjective meaning "unaccompanied".  It becomes "soli" in the dative case where you're most likely using it, but does decline to "solo" in the ablative case.

Comment: @BenVoigt — Interesting. So would it be (a) recto/verso/soli or (b) recto/verso/solo?

Comment: You need to know the context, in Latin adjectives get declined to match the noun that they modify, and the declension of the noun depends on its role in the sentence.  Are you thinking of a prepositional construction such as *in folio verso*?  Then yes, *soli* would correspond.

Comment: @BenVoigt — Actually, I'm just thinking of a construction where the words stand alone. This is for a small computer programming project that does page layout, and the layers of the software need to communicate with each other about how to align the content. So for now I have `recto`, `verso`, and `solo` as keywords in the enumeration of possibilities (internal strings, labels, variable names, and enumerations), but will change that to `soli` if the latter is a better parallel construct with the first two.

Comment: The base form (nominative) of these words is ["rectus"](https://www.online-latin-dictionary.com/latin-english-dictionary.php?lemma=RECTUS100), ["versus"](https://www.online-latin-dictionary.com/latin-english-dictionary.php?lemma=VERSUS300), ["solus"](https://www.online-latin-dictionary.com/latin-english-dictionary.php?lemma=SOLUS100)

Answer (score 12):

To begin with, *centro* isn't an adjective in Latin, so it can't be used in the same way as *recto* and *verso*.

I believe that in a document of the type that you're describing, all pages would be said to be recto pages.

For confirmation, I consulted Robert Bringhurst, *The elements of typographic style*. On p 74 (of the 4.0 version), Bringhurst describes recto and verso in terms that are as much functional as purely physical:

> In right-reading scripts..., the forward or recto page is the right-hand half of the two-page spread: the page that invites you to read and turn it. The facing page is the verso: the door you have come through, the page you have already turned. you can indeed go backward...but the natural flow is from what you have read to what you have not. In leftward-reading scripts such as Arabic and Hebrew, this implicit invitation runs the other way: the forward page, the recto, is on the left.
>
> To a bibliographer, the recto page, whether left or right, is the front and the verso the back of the leaf. To a typographer, as to a reader, the recto is a place to start.

The page, and chapter, then ends with a parenthetical paragraph that most directly applies to your case:

> (E-books, you will notice, consist of rectos only....)

Comment: Apparently I have been doing it wrong all those years, because I always read the left page first and then the right.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel: Just in case you're being serious: It is very common for rightward-reading books to start on the right page.  The inside title is on the right page, chapter titles (or story titles, in the case of anthologies) will be on the right page, story titles (e.g., in anythologies) tend to be on right pages, etc.  This means either leaving a page blank or intentionally tweaking chapter length so that things line up to end on the left page.  In my reference books, all the chapters start on odd-numbered (i.e., right) pages.

Comment: That's interesting; thanks. I still have a practical problem, though: In a simple page-layout system I'm putting together for myself, I need three unique words to distinguish among the three cases (front side [recto], back side [verso], only side [?]), so I can't use recto for the latter case, as it would ambiguously refer to two cases. Do you know if there is a Latin word for "the only side of the paper" or "no particular side of the paper"?

Comment: @ToddLehman. Why not just folio? Recto and verso are added for differentiation; if such differentiation isn't required, neither are the adjectives. Though someone could likely coin a Latin phrase for 'the only side of the paper', that phrase, unlike recto/verso, would have no force of tradition behind it (plus, though Latin in origin, recto and verso have become adopted as English words); so, absent an *established* Latin term for what you want, and assuming that your system won't be used solely by Latin speakers, why bother? Why not just say something like 'single-page' or 'undifferentiated'?

Comment: (The issue with using just 'folio' would be that the word 'folio' is traditionally used by typographers to refer to page numbers; but I don't think most people are aware of this technical use of the term.)

Comment: @ToddLehman The thing is, the pages in your single-page layout system will still have front and back sides, i.e. *recto* and *verso.* There are two separate concepts: 1) front/back side of the page, and 2) page layout. Your main concern however seems to be neither of these, but right/left **alignment of page content.** The terms *recto* and *verso* are only roundabout ways to get to this (typically *verso* is left-aligned). I don't see a good reason for this other than to add mystery. Using the terms left, right and center for left, right and center-aligned pages looks to me the way to go.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian — Well, actually, there aren't any front and back sides in my usage, because it's a purely digtal format. The solo pages are for stepping through the pages one at a time, and the verso-recto pairs are for stepping through the pages two at a time. The reader can choose 1-up or 2-up.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian: I think the point is that the alignment of page content is determined by the placement of the book binding -- online there is no binding, so the placement is different from either a bound left (rear-facing) leaf or a bound right (front-facing) leaf.

Comment: @ToddLehman I had this possibility in mind, but properly speaking it's still idependent of page layout. One can print-bind center-aligned pages, which will end up being recto or verso, or display right/left-aligned pages one page at a time in an unbound digital format. The independence of all these variables is what I'm getting at, and my suggestion is that it would be incorrect to describe page alignment using terms that specify whether it's the front or the back part of the leaf of paper that's being printed on.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian — I completely agree in the case of printed materials. However, in my case, this is purely digital. There's no paper and no front/back side. Only left/right pages in the case of a 2-up display or centered pages in the case of a 1-up (single-page) display.

Comment: @ToddLehman So you still have page alignment separately from page presentation, only you happen to make one dependent on the other. If your medium has no front and back sides, then as I say, using these concepts as roundabout ways to get at page alignment seems at best like unnecessary mystification. More importantly, there's no third, neither-nor term to use for the center alignment in a roundabout way, since the physical reality of print books has no space for it. Therefore my suggestion remains to use the straightforward aligment terms "left", "right" and "center".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's been suggested anywhere official (so I'd defer to cnread's source), but the first word I thought of that fit what you're looking for ("single-page-at-a-time reading") is actually [*singularis*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DS%3Aentry+group%3D46%3Aentry%3Dsingularis). From Lewis and Short:

> In gen., **one by one, one at a time, alone,** single, solitary

As an adjective with *folium*, you'd use the form *singulare*; as an adverb you'd use *singulariter* ("one by one, singly, separately"); and with the ablative *folio* you'd use the form *singulari*.